# Reverse for 'detail_page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail\\-page/(?P<slug>[^/]+)\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-urls

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('posts-page/', posts_page, name='posts_page'),
    path('detail-page/<slug>', detail_page, name='detail_page'),
]
```

views.py

```
def detail_page(request, slug):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    context = {
        'post': post,
    }

    return render(request, 'detail_page.html', context=context)
```

base.html

```
  <div class="navbar">
            <nav class="navigation hide" id="navigation">
                <span class="close-icon" id="close-icon" onclick="showIconBar()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'home_page' %}">Forums</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'posts_page' %}">Posts</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'detail_page' %}">Detail</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="bar-icon" id="iconBar" onclick="hideIconBar()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            <div class="brand">My Forum</div>
        </div>
```

detail_page.html

```
<!--Topic Section-->
<div class="topic-container">
    <!--Original thread-->
    <div class="head">
        <div class="authors">Author</div>
        <div class="content">Topic: {{ post.title }} (Read 1325 Times)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="body">
        <div class="authors">
            <div class="username"><a href="">{{ post.user.fullname }}</a></div>
            <div>Role</div>
            <img src="{{ post.user.profile_pic.url }}" alt="">
            <div>Posts: <u>45</u></div>
            <div>Points: <u>4586</u></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
           {{ post.content | safe }}
            <br>
            <div class="comment">
                <button onclick="showComment()">Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have objects in db and i try to get page with post and i get this error, i understand tha problem mix with slug and that something wrong with this argument, but i really idk why

Comment: Your `{% url 'detail_page' %}` needs the slug of a `Post`, so `{% url 'detail_page' some_slug %}` with `some_slug`, an expression to the slug of some post.

Comment: i added post_slug, added in views, base, urls and also get this error